# +++ Verwendung und Ursprung dreier Plus-Zeichen +++

Tags: punctuation

Ist die dreier-Plus Klammer im Titel im ganzen DACH-Gebiet verwendet? Ist deren Verwendung auf Eilmeldungen beschränkt? Auf wichtige Nachrichten bzw. Schlagzeilen? Und was ist deren Ursprung?

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nachrichtenticker

Comment: Meiner Meinung nach ist das reine Konvention. (Vermutungen, dass das noch aus der Telegramm-Zeit stammt, haben sich nicht bestätigen lassen.) Ticker (also die Lauftext-Anzeigen) sehen einfach blöd aus, wenn sich da gar nichts bewegt oder erst langsam hereinkriecht, weil die Meldung zu kurz für den Platz ist. Für banale Nachrichten gäbe es gar kein Laufband.

Comment: Die Antwort kann durch Google gefunden werden ist kein Schließgrund.

Comment: [meta: Embrace the non googlers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers)

Comment: Kommentare bereinigt. Bitte [seid nett](https://german.stackexchange.com/conduct). Weder Google-Funde noch Verwendung außerhalb des deutschen Sprachgebiets würde ich als validen Schließgrund sehen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Das ist jetzt keine von unbesiegbarer Sachkunde in der Typographiegeschichte diktierte Antwort. Aber nachdem diese eigentlich interessante Frage bisher nur wilde Kommentare aber keine vernünftigen Antworten bekommen hat, wage ich mich mal mit meinem semiprofessionellen Halbwissen vor, bzw. mit einer Erzählung aus der Welt des Journalismus:

Der "Nachrichtenticker" heißt so, weil in der Zeit, als es noch kein Internet gab, die Zeitungs- und anderen Redaktionen, die Nachrichten verbreiteten, alle einen Raum hatten, in dem jeweils eine ganze Reihe von Fernschreibern standen, über die von den großen Nachrichtenagenturen Nachrichten hereinkamen. Das war praktisch eine Übertragung über Telefon, und es wurde dann zu Papier gebracht über eine in den "Ticker" eingebaute elektrische Schreibmaschine, die den Text Buchstabe für Buchstabe aufs Papier hämmerte. Gesendet wurde das von den Nachrichtenagenturen wie dpa, afp, epd, und so weiter. Man hatte als Zeitungsverlag ein entsprechendes Abonnement, das übrigens horrend teuer war. (Ich habe was im Kopf von 20000 DM pro Monat für dpa, aber ich kann mich täuschen.)

"Ticker" wurden die Maschinen - auch in deutschen Redaktionsstuben - genannt, weil sie die ganze Zeit - tick-tick-tick - Buchstabe für Buchstabe vor sich hin schrieben. Und zwar nicht gerade mit rasender Geschwindigkeit. Die Telefonübertragung dauerte damals einfach rechte lange pro Anschlag.

Weil das nun letztlich einfach ferngesteuerte elektrische Schreibmaschinen waren, gab es keinerlei Möglichkeiten zur Schriftgestaltung außer, was eben der Zeichensatz der Schreibmaschine so hergab. Nachricht folgte auf Nachricht, Absatz folgte auf Absatz, und zwar alles auf einer einzigen langen Papierschlange, die sich der Redakteur, der die Nachrichten durchsah, dann zerschnitt.

Also musste man die Überschriften irgendwie hervorheben. "Groß und fett" schreiben wie heute auf den Computerbildschirmen ging wie gesagt nicht. Und eine ganze Linie z.B. aus "=" übers ganze Blatt zu ziehen, hätte viel zu viele Schreibmaschinenanschläge und damit auch Zeit (und Telefonleitungskapazität) gekostet. Da liegt es nahe, Überschriften mit etwas wie

+++ Das ist jetzt eine Überschrift +++

auszuzeichnen. Es fällt ins Auge, da drei "+" sonst einfach nirgends vorkommen, ist aber mit nur sechs zusätzlichen Anschlägen auch ökonomisch.

Hugh. Viele Grüße von einem alten Zeitungsredakteur. (Ja, ich habe selbst noch so einen "Ticker-Raum" gesehen, damals bei der Schwäbischen Zeitung in Leutkirch.)

**Oder kurz:** Meine Hypothese ist, dass die drei +++ von diesen Nachrichtentickern kommen, nicht etwa aus der Zeit der Telegramme. Historisch nachgeprüft habe ich es nicht. Insbesondere habe ich keine Ticker-Nachricht aus dieser Zeit aufbewahrt, mit der ich jetzt belegen (oder auch nur überprüfen) könnte, dass auf diesen Maschinen wirklich "+++" zur Auszeichnung von Überschriften verwendet wurde.

Wenn meine Hypothese stimmt, sollte man allerdings annehmen, dass die drei +++ nicht nur im deutschsprachigen Raum üblich waren. Nun, wäre ich Germanistik-Professor geworden, würde ich jetzt eine Master-Studentin auf dieses Thema ansetzen.

Comment: Danke schön für die Antwort. Ich lese kaum österreichische Zeitungen, und in der Schweiz hatte ich keine Zeit, die +++ zu sehen (auf srf.ch zB sehe ich dies nicht). Ist es eine rein (bundes)deutsche Sache, oder anderswo zu finden? In den gelöschten Kommentaren hieß es, es sei quasi offensichtlich, dass es international ist. Aber in keiner Sprache der Wikipedia fand ich die drei Plus (in den jeweiligen Artikeln zum Ticker).

Comment: @c.p.  Man muss unterscheiden zwischen den Ausdrucken der (damaligen!) Nachrichtenticker in der Vor-Internet-und-Vor-PC-Zeit (wo nach meiner Hypothese die drei +++ herkommen) und der Verwendung der drei +++ in heutigen Print- und Online-Medien. Da sind sie natürlich ein reines Stilmittel (nicht mal eine "Konvention", wie einer der Kommentare meinte), und zwar, vermute ich, weil Leute die drei +++ irgendwie als Indidkatoren nachrichtendienstlich-journalistischer Professionalität wahrnehmen. (Auch dies nur eine Hypothese).

Comment: (Forts). Spricht man nun von den einzeiligen Text-Laufbändern, die oft am unteren Rand von Fernsehbildern eingeblendet werden sowie - ausgehend davon - auch als Elemente auf Websites eingesetzt werden (oder wurden): Hier werden die drei +++ vermutlich aus ähnlichen Gründen genommen wie - laut Hypothese - bei den alten Nachrichtentickern: Das + wird sonst praktisch nicht verwendet und ist ein visuell klar erkennbares Zeichen. Und irgendwie muss man in einzeligen Laufbändern ja zeigen "Hier fängt ein neuer Text an".